# Visual Sudio, как включить в сборку?

Tags: visual-studio

Есть проект на `ASP Core 3 + Angular 8`, который хорошо собирается.

Есть отдельный проект на `NodeJS`, который выполняет свою логику и который запускается своей командой, то есть простой скрипт, включающий `express js`.

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы при сборке проекта asp core, проект на ноде автоматически копировался при публикации в папку с публикацией и запускался тоже от   запуска проекта asp core, мне оставалось только установить зависимости `npm i` и все.

По факту, сейчас я публикую  проект, копирую туда свой node проект, устанавливаю зависимости и запускаю отдельной консолью.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/specifying-custom-build-events-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 Я в этом не разбираюсь, но, возможно, это поможет

Comment: Гуглите по ключевому слову "msbuild". Любой проект студии является одновременно сборочным файлом msbuild (ну или msbuild core) и его можно редактировать для настройки сборки.